# Build Loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have the code below which I would like to build a loop for:

```
    Ten0 = dbGetQuery(conn, "select  * from yyyy where tenure=0")
    Ten0_alg = readRDS(file = "t0_scoring.rda")
    new <- survfit(Ten0_alg, newdata = Ten0)
    Ten0_scored <- cbind(Ten0,tmp)
```

What I would like to do is increment the number 0, from 0 to 24 and execute the code each time the number increments in an automated manner.

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Comment: can you explain more, do you need all the intermediate variables or are you only concerned with the end result?

Comment: How are you using *new*? Do you want to return the `dbGetQuery` or `survfit` results? And does the RDS file increment: t0, t1, t2, ...?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**

While you *can* do this with a loop that features "variable varnames" you might consider adapting your data structure such that it does not rely on "variable varnames"

**How to do variable varnames in R:**

Use the eval-parse trick, where the command is a string which is parsed and evaluated using the respective commands.

```
for (i in 0:24) {

  cmd <- paste0("Ten",i," = dbGetQuery(conn, \"select  * from yyyy where tenure=",i,"\");
      Ten",i,"_alg = readRDS(file = \"t",i,"_scoring.rda\");
      new <- survfit(Ten",i,"_alg, newdata = Ten",i,");
      Ten",i,"_scored <- cbind(Ten",i,",tmp)")

  eval(parse(text=cmd))

}
```

This code block was produced by replacing `"` with `\"` and `0` with `",i,"` in the code you provided.

**What you could do instead:**

1. Define a vector of values you want to evaluate over and u se functions that apply functions over vectors or lists (see `?lapply`), e.g.

`tenures <- 0:24`
`Tan <- lapply(tenures, function(x) dbGetQuery(conn, paste0("select  * from yyyy where tenure=",x))`

2. Define a mock function that will calculate your results for a given number, e.g.

`getResults <- function(conn, file, tenure) {`

```
 Ten0 = dbGetQuery(conn, paste0("select  * from yyyy where 
 tenure=",tenure))
 Ten0_alg = readRDS(file = file)
 new <- survfit(Ten0_alg, newdata = Ten0)
 Ten0_scored <- cbind(Ten0,tmp)

# return all results
return(list(Ten0=Ten0,Ten0_alg=Ten0_alg,new=new,Ten0_scored=Ten0_scored))
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to place all those code lines in a string call? Do not recommend `eval(parse(...))`.

Comment: I also do not recommend it. Which is why I stated it in the answer and gave examples on what else could be done.